# why it didnt compute the netincome and deduction?

Tags: c

[image]

[image]

Hello , Iam really struggling rightnow. This program should compute the deduction and total net income. there is no error in the program. but why it didnt  compute the "DEDUCTION" and the "NET INCOME" Iam using C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{



  int withholdingtax;
  int sss_contribution;
  int salary;
  int netincome;
  int deduction;



  printf ("ENTER SALARY :" ,&salary);
  scanf("%d" ,&salary);
  printf("\n");

  printf ("ENTER WITHHOLDING TAX :" ,&withholdingtax);
  scanf ("%d" , &withholdingtax);
  printf("\n");

  printf ("SSS CONTRIBUTION :" ,&sss_contribution);
  scanf ("%d" , &sss_contribution);
  printf ("\n");

  deduction = (sss_contribution + withholdingtax);
  netincome = (salary = deduction);

  printf ("TOTAL DEDUCTION :" , &deduction);
  printf ("\n");

  printf ("TOTAL NET INCOME :" , &netincome);


    


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please when it comes to code or debugging/output never resource to images

Answer (score 0):

> `printf ("ENTER SALARY :" ,&salary);`

When just printing a string, do not include any extra arguments. Use:

`printf("Enter salary: ");`

> `printf ("TOTAL DEDUCTION :" , &deduction);`
> `printf ("\n");`

To print a number, include a conversion specification, like `%d` to format an `int` value as a decimal numeral, and pass the value of the object, not its address, and include the new-line character in the same `printf`, not a separate one:

`printf("Total deduction: %d\n", deduction);`

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am new at programming , thank you so much for the clear answer.